# how can I change the date of window scheduler task via a admin webpage?

Tags: .net, scheduled-tasks

how can I create window scheduler task via a c# **webpage** ?

I have an Exe that I want to run once or twice a week.
this task should run even if the website is down.

Comment: just found out about Task Scheduler interface, I have update my answer as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383600(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule task through dos commands at command prompt. Please see this article [How to Create, Modify and Delete Scheduled Tasks from the Command Line](http://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/)
You can execute dos command through aspx. See this article [Running DOS Command Inside aspx Pages](http://wiki.customware.net/repository/display/SharePoint/Running+DOS+Command+Inside+aspx+Pages). Combining these two you can come up with commands to schedule or modify existing scheduled commands in windows through a web page in asp.net. Hope this helps

EDIT: Found out that there is a [Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383600%28VS.85%29.aspx), Also check this article from codeproject: [A New Task Scheduler Class Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2407/A-New-Task-Scheduler-Class-Library-for-NET)

Comment: Great idea I will wait to hear if there is another way.